# Prevent CasperJS from exiting when all steps are complete

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I have a dynamic CasperJS suite, that works around WebServer built-in in PhantomJS. New steps are added dynamically to the suite.

However, right now, Casper exists as soon as all pending steps are completed.

How do I prevent it from automatically closing and wait for more steps to be added dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a `onComplete` function to `casper.run()`, if the `onComplete` function never ends, the casper won't exit. Try this code:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: "debug",
});

casper.start()

casper.then(function () {
    casper.echo("the first step")
})

casper.then(function () {
    casper.echo("the second step")
})

casper.then(function () {
    casper.echo("the third step")
})

casper.run(function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        casper.echo('step: ' + casper.step)
    }, 1000)
})
```